# Why comparison operator == does not work for strings in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl. I want to understand why does == operator is treating both these strings alike? It works ok if I use eq instead if ==. If name is kuldeep or rahul, it prints 'Right name'.

```
my $name="kuldeep";

if ($name == "rahul")
{
  print 'Right name!',"\n";
}
else
{
  print 'Wrong name!','\n';
}
```

Comment: `==` is for numbers, `eq` for strings. You have to tell Perl which way you want to treat a scalar value as.

Comment: Read https://perldoc.pl/perldata#Scalar-values

Answer (score 11):

You are mistaken. The numerical equality comparison operator works perfectly fine with strings!

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say "123" == "123.0" ? "same" : "different"'
same

$ perl -e'CORE::say "123" == "123.1" ? "same" : "different"'
different
```

In your example, you are asking Perl to compare the numerical value of the string `kuldeep` (zero with a warning) with the numerical value of the string `rahul` (zero with a warning), and they are indeed equal.

ALWAYS USE `use strict; use warnings;`!!!

And use `eq` to compare strings.

Answer (score 6):

Interpreter realizes (from the == operator) that it's doing a numeric comparison.  The value of $name is converted to a numeric, which gets you a 0.  "rahul" is converted to a numeric, which is a 0.  0 == 0, so that's true, and thus "Right name" is chosen.

If I compare it against my name, works the same way.

However, if there really is a string with a number in it, like you made either string "12345" (specifically with the quotes), Perl will assume you knew what you were doing by requesting the == operator, and will dutifully auto-convert ("cast" in programmer-speak) that to numeric 12345.  Then your comparison will fail.

TL/DR: use 'eq' for string comparison!  :-)

Comment: Sorry, @zdim is absolutely correct.  I wasn't trying to say that this was destructive to the variable $name, that it was changed in any way.  I was trying not to tie my sentence up in too many details, even though I couldn't help myself and used the term "cast" later.

Comment: Oh, also, adding since you're new to Perl, that it'd be much more common to write:
    print "Right name!\n";

Comment: "_I wasn't trying to say that this was destructive to the variable_" -- I thought so and commented just so that the phrasing is adjusted to be accurate. This was done (thanks to ikegami) and I've removed the comment